# how to use cutom tags to preprocess data and store it in jsp hiddent input

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, custom-tags, scriptlet

Hi I have written a below scriplet which will fetch me data from the properties file. Now I want to make it as a custom tag as java code inside jsp is not adviced.

```
ApplicationContext appCtx =      WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(config.getServletContext());
ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource mySpringBean = (ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource)    appCtx.getBean("messageSource");
String gridColumnValues=mySpringBean.getMessage("propertyfile", null,  locale)
```

Now i am setting this string to my hiddent input value.

How to convert this into the custom tag

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to create a class to do the work of the custom tag.  It should inherit from `javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.SimpleTagSupport`.  If the desired output is a hidden html input tag, you'll probably want attributes for `id` and `name`.  The user of the custom tag should provide these, so they become fields of the custom tag class with getters and setters.  The user also will specifying which property to get from the spring bean, so that will also be a field in the class.

```
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspException;
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter;
import javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.SimpleTagSupport;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils;

public class MyCustomTag extends SimpleTagSupport {

    private String name;
    private String id;
    private String property;

    @Override
    public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {
        // Overriding doTag() from SimpleTagSupport, you do your Java work.
        try {
            PageContext pc = (PageContext) getJspContext();
            ServletContext sc = pc.getServletContext();
            ApplicationContext appCtx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(sc);

            ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource mySpringBean = (ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource)appCtx.getBean("messageSource");

            // use this.property to allow your tag's user to get any message from the bean.
            String gridColumnValues = mySpringBean.getMessage(this.property, null, Locale.US);

            // write your desired output, in this case a complete hidden html form field
            JspWriter out = pc.getOut();

            out.print("<input type=\"hidden\" ");
            if (this.name != null)
                out.print("name=\"" + this.name + "\" ");
            if (this.id != null)
                out.print("id=\"" + this.id + "\" ");

            out.println("value=\"" + gridColumnValues + "\"/>");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new JspException(e);
        }

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public void setProperty(String property) {
        this.property = property;
    }

}
```

Next, create a tld file `/WEB-INF/tld/mycustomtag.tld`.  This file defines the custom tag and identifies the class above by name.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE taglib PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JSP Tag Library 1.2//EN"
                        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-jsptaglibrary_1_2.dtd">
<taglib>

    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <jsp-version>2.0</jsp-version>
    <short-name>MyCustomTag</short-name>
    <uri>http://example.com/mytags</uri>

    <tag>
        <name>custom</name>  <!-- The name is how your users will invoke the tag in a jsp.  You can call it anything you want. -->
        <tag-class>com.example.MyCustomTag</tag-class>
        <body-content>empty</body-content>
        <attribute>
            <name>name</name>
            <required>false</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>id</name>
            <required>false</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>property</name>
            <required>true</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>        
    </tag>

</taglib>
```

To use this in a jsp, declare your custom tag library with a taglib directive.  The prefix will be the xml namespace you want your tag to use.  In this example I called it "my".  The tag's name from the tld file is "custom", so it would be called with `<my:custom/>`

```
<%@ taglib prefix="my" uri="http://example.com/mytags" %>

<my:custom id="myhiddenfield" name="hiddenname" property="propertyfile"/>
```

When you run this and view the html source, you'll see a hidden input tag with the value of your Spring bean's message.